# How to get value using Redistemplate in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

This is a code that gonna put key and value in Redis

```
    public void putCache(String categoryCode, String subCategoryCode)  {
        String key = REDIS_KEY + categoryCode + ":" + subCategoryCode;
        String value =  (String) redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);
        HashOperations<String, String, String> hash = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
        Map<String, String> MapCache = new HashMap<>();
        MapCache.put(key,value);
        hash.putAll(key,MapCache);
        }
```

When i run the program , it say that my value is null.
How can i fix it? [Picture that value in Redis in null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocI2U.png)

```
    public void spriteGetData() {
    List<SpriteEntity> spriteEntity = spriteRepo.findAll();
    for (SpriteEntity entities : spriteEntity) {
        String categoryCode = entities.getCategoryCode();
        String subCategoryCode = entities.getSubCategoryCode();
        redisService.putCache(categoryCode, subCategoryCode);
    }
```

This one is use to get data from db and put it in Redis.

Comment: Hi! I think that you should focus on this line: *String value =  (String) redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);* It returns null, which is then inserted to Redis. Could you just check if the key used in *get* method is corrent?

Comment: Also it looks like *get* returns *null* when the key does not exist (source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ValueOperations.html#get-java.lang.Object-).